# Use proofs and witness constructions inside function definitions in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to formalize some intuitionistic notions. One of these is the continuity principle. In Coq I defined this as:

```
(* Infinite sequences *)
Definition N := nat -> nat.

(* The first n elements of a and b coincide. *)
Definition con (a b : N) n := forall i, i < n -> a i = b i.

(* Brouwers Continuity Principle *)
Axiom BCP :
  forall (R : N -> nat -> Prop),
  (forall a, exists n, R a n) ->
  (forall a, exists m n, forall b, con a b m -> R b n).
```

I want to generalize this to so called spreads. A spread is a subset of the Baire space that can be thought of as a tree with only infinite branches. A decider o (called the spread law) takes a finite starting sequence and returns 0 if it should be in the spread. When a sequence s is in the spread at least one extension n :: s must also be in the spread. The empty sequence must be accepted such that the spread is inhabited. I defined this as follows:

```
(* Spread law *)
Definition Spr_Law (o : list nat -> nat) :=
  o [] = 0 /\ forall s, o s = 0 <-> exists n, o (n :: s) = 0.
```

One way to prove that the continuity principle generalizes to arbitrary spreads is to define a function that 'retracts' N onto a spread defined by such a decider o. This is where I get stuck because I simply do not know enough about Coq to define this well. First of all, I inserted a picture of this definition from the course notes.
[image: informal definition]

The trouble is that this definition includes a 'smallest m such that o accepts m :: s'. This is not a terminating procedure in general and I do not know how to use `Function` to prove that this search would terminate for our purposes (it will since a spread law must accept at least one extension).

I found that I can use the `Coq.Logic.ConstructiveEpsilon` library to get a witness when I have an exists statement. I could pass the condition that at least one extension exists to the function. Based on this I created the following code (this is only the first part of the definition, which maps finite sequences onto the spread):

```
Definition find_extension o s (w : exists n, o (n :: s) = 0) : nat :=
  constructive_ground_epsilon_nat (fun n => o (n :: s) = 0) (decider_dec o s) w.

(* Compute retraction for finite start sequences. *)
Fixpoint rho o (w : forall s, o s = 0 -> exists n, o (n :: s) = 0)
  (s : list nat) : list nat :=
  match s with
  | [] => []
  | n :: s => let t := rho o w s in
    if o (n :: t) =? 0
    then n :: t
    else (find_extension o t (w t {?????})) :: t
  end.
```

Now I encounter the real problem. The `{?????}` part is where I need to insert a proof that `o t = 0`. This holds since rho only ever returns sequences that are accepted by the decider o. Perhaps I can let rho return a tuple containing the new sequence together with a proof that this sequence is accepted (such that I can feed it into `w` after recursion), but I do not know how. Note that this is especially tricky for the else branch since the proof that this value is accepted holds because the witness is valid.

Of course alternative ideas for defining spreads are also welcome. I do feel that this is achievable though (there are no logical inconsistencies as far as I can see).

Comment: It would be useful if you could separate your edits from the question and post them as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have figured something out:

```
(* Only sequences that are accepted by o *)
Inductive spr (o : decider) :=
  | spr_s s : o s = 0 -> spr o.

(* Return smallest n such that o accepts n :: s. *)
Definition find_extension o s (witness : exists n, o (n :: s) = 0) : spr o :=
  let P := (fun n => o (n :: s) = 0) in
  let D := (decider_dec o s) in
  spr_s o
    ((constructive_ground_epsilon_nat P D witness) :: s)
    (constructive_ground_epsilon_spec_nat P D witness).

(*
To generalize BCP to spreads we first define a function that retracts the Baire
space onto an arbitrary spread given its spread law. This happens in two steps.
*)

(* Compute retraction for finite start sequences. *)
Fixpoint rho o
  (Hnil : o [] = 0)
  (Hcons : forall s, o s = 0 -> exists n, o (n :: s) = 0)
  (s : list nat) : spr o :=
  match s with
  | [] => spr_s o [] Hnil
  | n :: s =>
    match rho o Hnil Hcons s with
    | spr_s _ t Ht =>
      match eq_dec (o (n :: t)) 0 with
      | left Heq  => spr_s o (n :: t) Heq
      | right  _  => find_extension o t (Hcons t Ht)
      end
    end
  end.

(* Retraction of N onto F_o *)
Definition retract o
  (Hnil : o [] = 0)
  (Hcons : forall s, o s = 0 -> exists n, o (n :: s) = 0)
  : N -> N :=
  fun a => fun n =>
    match rho o Hnil Hcons (get (n + 1) a) with
    | spr_s _ [] _ => 0 (* not reachable *)
    | spr_s _ (rho_n :: _) _ => rho_n
    end.
```